# Help with LINQ Projection

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have an an `ICollection<Product>`:

`var products = productRepository.FindAll();`

`Product` has a property called `Orders`, which is an `ICollection<Order>`.

I'm trying to end up with an `ICollection<Order>`, for a given **CustomerId**.

In other words:

> Given a collection of products, i want to retrieve a list of orders for a particular customer

Here's what i have:

```
var orders = products
               .Where(x => x.Orders != null)
               .Where(x => x.Orders.Any(y => y.CustomerId == 10))
               .Select(x => x.Orders)
               .ToList();
```

But i end up with an `List<ICollection<Order>>`, where i want a `ICollection<Order>`.

Do i have to do some kind of grouping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
var orders = products
           .Where(x => x.Orders != null)
           .Where(x => x.Orders.Any(y => y.CustomerId == 10))
           .SelectMany(x => x.Orders)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, that's it - for some reason i totally forgot about `SelectMany`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the collection of orders for single product then this would work

```
var orders = products
               .Where(x => x.Orders != null)
               .Where(x => x.Orders.Any(y => y.CustomerId == 10))
               .Select(x => x.Orders)
               .Single();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what i want.

Comment: @RPM1984 Its okay, today I learnt `SelectMany` in LINQ. Big Thanks to you and @zerkms... :D